# Access a variable defined in initializers folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a file `config/initializers/test.rb` that defines a variable:

```rb
# config/initializers/test.rb

name = "hi"
```

How can I access this variable `name` in other parts of my code, such as a model or controller?

Comment: The existing stack overflow answers did not work for me, such as using ```@name``` or ```::name```

Comment: Would having a static class in lib achieve the same goal? Why do you need it in initializers?

Comment: Use a constant instead, `NAME = "hi"`. Or a global var, `$name = "hi"`.

Comment: @Sixty4Bit: looks like this is setting up part of program state. Initializers folder is the place for this type of code.

Comment: Thank you, doing ```NAME = "hi"``` worked. I didn't know ruby does something special if the variable name is all caps.

Comment: `ENV['NAME'] = 'hi'`would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case, you should use CONSTANT or $global_variable

```
NAME = "I AM CONSTANT"
```

### or

```
$name = "i am global variable"
```